# WebSocket to Binance: Connection closed error

Tags: java, spring-websocket, binance

I am trying trying to create a WebSocket and connect to Binance.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    WebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();

    WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(client);
    stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());

    StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new MyWebSocketHandler();
    stompClient.connect("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws", sessionHandler);

    new Scanner(System.in).nextLine(); // Don't close immediately.

}

private static class MyWebSocketHandler implements StompSessionHandler {

    @Override
    public void afterConnected(StompSession stompSession, StompHeaders stompHeaders) {
        System.out.println("connected");
        stompSession.send(stompHeaders, "{\"method\": \"SUBSCRIBE\", \"params\":[\"btcusdt@trade\"], \"id\": 1}");
    }

    @Override
    public void handleException(StompSession stompSession, StompCommand stompCommand, StompHeaders stompHeaders, byte[] bytes, Throwable throwable) {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTransportError(StompSession stompSession, Throwable throwable) {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders stompHeaders) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleFrame(StompHeaders stompHeaders, Object o) {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get `Connection closed`:

```
org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.ConnectionLostException: Connection closed
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.DefaultStompSession.afterConnectionClosed(DefaultStompSession.java:523)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient$WebSocketTcpConnectionHandlerAdapter.afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketStompClient.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketHandlerDecorator.afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.afterConnectionClosed(LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.onClose(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:145)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusEndpointWrapper.onClose(TyrusEndpointWrapper.java:1190)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusWebSocket.onClose(TyrusWebSocket.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.frame.CloseFrame.respond(CloseFrame.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.ProtocolHandler.process(ProtocolHandler.java:658)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.TyrusClientEngine$TyrusReadHandler.handle(TyrusClientEngine.java:668)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientFilter$ProcessTask.execute(GrizzlyClientFilter.java:472)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.TaskProcessor.processTask(TaskProcessor.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.TaskProcessor.processTask(TaskProcessor.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyClientFilter.java:270)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

I also observed in logger this message: `closed with CloseStatus[code=1008, reason=Invalid request]`

My imports are these:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tyrus-standalone-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a step. You have to request a listen-key first, which is then used to register/connect to the websocket.

https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#listen-key-spot

POST /api/v3/userDataStream